# In the Linux kernel, what is the arch folder for?

Tags: kernel

I was looking inside the Linux kernel source code, and I noticed a folder named 'arch.' And I was wondering, what is that folder for? Is it for Arch Linux, or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It holds [architecture-specific code](https://courses.linuxchix.org/kernel-hacking-2002/08-overview-kernel-source.html).

> All the architecture specific code is in this directory and in the include/asm- directories. Each architecture has its own directory underneath this directory. For example, the code for a PowerPC based computer would be found under arch/ppc. You will find low-level memory management, interrupt handling, early initialization, assembly routines, and much more in these directories.

If you [look](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch?h=v4.16.7), you can see the different directories for architectures like x86, ARM etc....